# Django: Avoid HTTP API calls while testing from django views

Tags: django, django-testing

I'm writing the tests for django views, Some of the views are making the external HTTP requests. While running the tests i dont want to execute these HTTP requests. Since during tests , data is being used is dummy and these HTTP requests will not behave as expected.

What could be the possible options for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where mocking comes in. In your tests, you can use libraries to patch the parts of the code you are testing to return the results you expect for the test, bypassing what that code actually does.

You can read a good blog post about mocking in Python [here](http://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python).

If you are on Python 3.3 or later, the [mock](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html) library is included in Python. If not, you can download it from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock).

The exact details of how to mock the calls you're making will depend on what exactly your view code looks like.

Comment: nice article that you shared, this can be used to mock certain part of code. But not getting how django view can be tested as whole.

Answer (score 3):

You could override settings in your tests and then check for that setting in your view. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings) are the docs to override settings.

```
from django.conf import settings
if not settings.TEST_API:
    # api call here
```

Then your test would look something like this

```
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings

class LoginTestCase(TestCase):

    @override_settings(TEST_API=True)
    def test_api_func(self):
        # Do test here
```

Since it would be fairly messy to have those all over the place I would recommend creating a mixin that would look something like this.

```
class SensitiveAPIMixin(object):
    def api_request(self, url, *args, **kwargs):
        from django.conf import settings
        if not settings.TEST_API:
            request = api_call(url)
            # Do api request in here
        return request
```

Then, through the power of multiple inheritence, your views that you need to make a request to this api call you could do something similar to this.

```
class View(generic.ListView, SensitiveAPIMixin):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = self.api_request('http://example.com/api1')
```

Comment: does not seems elegant solution to plug this condition through out the application code,

Comment: You're right, if you were doing that manually everywhere. But that is where inheritance comes in. I would probably create a custom base view or just a really easy mixin and a basic function that just makes the api call with a given URL that checks those settings and then just use that function throughout the app. I can show you what that would look like if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Ben is right on, but here's some psuedo-ish code that might help. The patch here assumes you're using `requests`, but change the path as necessary to mock out what you need.

```
from unittest import mock
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    @mock.patch('requests.post') # this is all you need to stop the API call
    def test_my_view_that_posts_to_an_api(self, mock_get):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('my-view-name'))

        self.assertEqual('my-value', response.data['my-key'])
        # other assertions as necessary
```